# How to create Eigen matrix out of 2 vectors

Tags: c++, eigen

I have 2 vectors and a matrix:

```
VectorXd A;
VectorXd B;
MatrixXd C;
```

How should I efficiently (without explicit loops and working fast)
compute matrix C values so that

```
C(i,k) = A(i) * B(k);
```

Assume that matrix C already has appropriate dimensions.

IMPORTANT: I only need help in using built-in Eigen syntax. Please no CUDA/MKL/BLAS suggestions. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to do this without loops or do it as efficiently as possible? The minimum complexity shall be A.size()*B.size() because these are the number of elements you wish to calculate.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Thank you for the answer. I do understand asymptotic algorithmic complexity is always O(A.size() * B.size()), but coefficient matters. And Eigen has unusual syntax so I just do not know how to write the expression without loops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for an outer product which is just a standard matrix product:

```
C = A * B.transpose();
```

Since the destination `c` does not alias with the operand of the product you can save one temporary with:

```
C.noalias() = A * B.transpose();
```

`noalias` makes sense for matrix products only.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I actually need.